# Issue with Cr10 Viewer being called from a control on a 64bit OS

Tags: winforms, crystal-reports, vb6

We are having an issue calling the Crystal ActiveX Report Viewer 10 control from a VB6 control that is placed on a .net form in a 64bit environment.

This does work on my 32bit development machine but when it is ran on a 64bit machine it is failing.

As soon as the form is attempted to be shown returns the error: 0xC000041D
Load Form1   (Form1 just has the Crystal Report Viewer on the form)
Form1.Show vbModal

The link provided is a Sample Project demonstrating the error I’m receiving:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4psacu98xs7uux8/DemoProject_CR10_axc.zip?dl=0

This consists of:
- VB6 Project (Project1)
- Custom control with a button calling Form1. (UserControl1.ctl)
- Form with the CR10 Viewer (Form1) 
- .Net Project (TestCr10)
- Form with UserControl1 placed on it.

To reproduce run the TestCr10 project and select the “ClickMe” button.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to `install the 32bit` Cr Run time on your deployment pc Also with vb run time.

Good luck!

Comment: I ran the cr10 32bit run time, and the vb6 runtime on the machine but I am still getting the same error.